# Авторизация через сесиию

Tags: php, сессия, авторизация

Помогите внести ясность в простом вопросе, изучаю php, не могу понять одну простую вещь с переходом по адресу в теге action.

Делаю так, в файле `auth.php` проверяю пустой инпут или нет, если нет старную сессию и добавляю в гл.массив auth =true

```
//auth.php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['test'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
    } else {
        echo 'Пустой инпут';
        ?>
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input name="test">
            <input type="submit" value="SEND">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
```

Захожу во второй файл  `index.php` и проверяю, выводится true, сессия работает на этом этапе все понятно.

```
//index.php
session_start(); //стартуем сессию
if (!empty($_SESSION['auth'])) { echo 'true'} else { echo 'false'; }
```

Но если я в файле `auth.php` в теге action прописываю `action="index.php"`, то при перенаправлении на  index.php получаю false.

Я так понимаю это связано с тем, что в первом случае файл `auth.php` считывается два раза и в итоге стартует сессию и В `$_SESSION['auth']` пишет `true`, а втором случае повторное считывание не происходит и идет перенаправление сразу в `index.php`, где по сути `$_SESSION['auth']` вовсе нет.

Как быть в такой ситуации не могу понять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происходит все корректно, в первом случае:

1. вы заходите на страницу `auth.php`, заполняете поле, жмете кнопку отправки
2. При отправке формы с пустым `action` браузер отправляет запрос к текущему скрипту, то есть опять `auth.php`, условие выполняется, в сессию записывается нужное значение.
3. вы переходите к файлу `index.php`, нужное значение уже в сессии

во втором случае вы исправляете `action` на `index.php` поэтому при отправке формы запрос уходит именно туда. Никакие параметры формы уже не проверяются, в сессию  ничего не записывается, т.к. скрипт обработки формы стал другим.

Если вам необходимо после проверки данных формы переправить пользователя на другой скрипт, то обработчик формы следует оставить пустым (или явно `auth.php`), а после указания значений сессии программно перенаправить запрос на другой файл

```
 ....
 $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit();
```

При этом будет сформирован HTTP ответ с кодом 302, сервер отправит браузеру новый URL, по которому браузер автоматически и перейдет.

Перед вызовом `header` не должно быть никакого другого вывода данных, либо придется очистить буфер вывода с помощью `ob_clean`

Comment: Я полагал что примерно такое решение будет предложено.
Предложенный мною пример далек от реального, но насколько это правильно использовать на практике?

Comment: что именно насколько правильно? делать редирект?

Comment: да, переадресация не через action формы а через header

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть три файла (некоторые файлы могут быть объединены в один)

1. Файл с формой
2. Файл обработчик формы
3. Произвольный файл

А дальше все просто

- **Во всех** файлах всегда должен идти запуск сессии `session_start()`
- В файле обработчики формы (тот который указан в атрибуте `action`) должна осуществляться проверка полей формы и устанавливаться или сбрасываться флаг аутентификации

  ```
  if (password_valid())
    $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
  else
    unset($_SESSION['auth']);
  ```
- При необходимости проверить аутентификацию в любом месте программы, должен выполняться код

  ```
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  ```

Answer (score -1):

empty — Проверяет, пуста ли переменная. Если вы не создавали $_SESSION['auth']  то будет ошибка. Проверяйте существование isset($_SESSION['auth'])

```
файл index.php

session_start();
//  если есть сесия 
if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
  echo 'true';
}
// иначе - подключаем форму
else{
  include 'auth.php';
}

файл auth.php

// Если есть переданный из формы пароль
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
} else {
  // иначе выводим форму
  echo 'Пустой инпут';
  // не передавайте пароли в адресной строке. это плохая практика.
  // Также првоеряйте имена передаваемых и получаемых переменных. Если передаём пароль то и получать должны пароль.
  // Вы же передавали поле с именем test, а пытались получить $_REQUEST['password']
  ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND">
  </form>
  <?php
}
```